# Convenient data structure and querying for message application using Firebase Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to implement live messaging in my application and I cannot seem to think of a convenient data structure inside Firestore. My current structure looks like this:

[image: My current structure]

**collection("conversations").document(id).collection("messages")**

Each document holds two attributes **user1** and **user2** with nicknames of contributors to the conversation. Each document also owns a collection called **messages** which holds documents where each represents a single message sent with some info.

What I'm trying to do next is to check if the conversation already exists, if not then create it. The problem for me is write a correct query to find out if it exists.

My first idea was: create **users** array instead which holds nicknames of users and then simply query:

```
db.collection("conversations").whereField("users", in: ["username1", "username2"])
```

Problem with this is that it means "where **users** contains **username1** OR **username2**", but I need it to contain "**username1** AND **username2**".
I tried to be smart and chain the **whereField** function as following:

```
db.collection("conversations").whereField("users", arrayContains: "username1").whereField("users", arrayContains: "username2")
```

Turns out that you cannot use arrayContains more than once in a single query.
After that I came back to the structure as displayed on the screenshot with **user1** and **user2** and ran a new query:

```
db.collection("conversations").whereField("user1", isEqualTo: user).whereField("user2", isEqualTo: friend)
```

This query is ran in a function where **user** and **friend** are string parameters holding nicknames of both sender and receiver of the message we're currently sending. Imagine you are sending a message, **user** is always going to be your nickname and **friend** the receiver's one. The problem with the query is that you're nickname might be saved under **user1** or **user2** and receiver's nickname aswell. In either of those situations the conversation exists. How would I have to change the query since I don't know in an advance who will have which position in the query aswell as in Firestore. Running the last query that I included twice while switching **user** and **friend** parameter seems very unconvenient.
Any tips or solutions to progress in this problem will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to do something specific with the Firebase API?

Comment: Yes I need to either change the structure in Firestore or change the query so I can get the desired result which I described above.